# Circle transformation outside of circle

Tags: python, rotation, geometry, trigonometry

I'm trying to rotate a rectangle based on the position of the mouse inside or outside of the circle.

The way I see it, if I can determine the point on the circle that is closest to the position of the mouse, I can then transform the rectangle along the circle using that point as the target.

I cannot however, figure out how to find that position. I thought that perhaps by using y=mx+b to follow the line from the mouse pos until it hits the point on the circle.

The problem with this however is that I do not have all of the points on the circle and there are hundreds if not thousands of points on the circle.

If the mouse position is outside of a circle, how do I find the point on the circle closest to the mouse-position?

Comment: It's very unclear what you want as you don't seem to have even asked a question. Please clarify your post.

Comment: edited, let me know if it is still unclear

Comment: Do you have any code that you've worked with so far? What libraries/packages are you using? Without this kind of information it is unlikely that someone will be able to help you.

Comment: Im using python and pygame

Answer (score 0):

Use `math.atan2()` to get the angle of the cursor from the center. The circle will be a fixed distance from the center, so you can just convert the angle and distance to a point on the circle with more trig.

```
angle = math.atan2(ymouse - ycenter, xmouse - xcenter)
```